# coldfusion continue keyword within IF block in cfscript / Odd behaviour

Tags: if-statement, coldfusion, cfml, continue

Has anyone noticed this odd behaviour with the Continue word. It seems to kill all following code in the template when used within an If statement.

I tested this in CF and Lucee with http://cflive.net/

eg:

```
<cfscript>
    writeoutput('test1, loop<br>');
    for (x = 0; x > 5; x++) {
        writeoutput(' gonna continue?');
        continue;
        writeoutput('continued within');
    }
    writeoutput('Out of loop..<br><br>');
    writeoutput('test2, if<br>');
    oURL = true;
    if (oURL) {
        writeoutput(' gonna continue?');
        continue; // seems to kill all following code
        writeoutput('continued within');
    }
    writeoutput(' out of If..');
    writeoutput(' end');
    for (x = 0; x > 5; x++) {
        writeoutput('loop:' & x);
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Continue would abort processing of the rest of the code within a loop. Seems to be working correctly to me. Docs http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fdf.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fe7

Comment: @Scp - FWIW, I do see the same result, but .. am curious, why use `continue` inside an if statement, instead of restructuring the if block? Usually continue is designed to work with loops.  Not sure what the expected behavior is when used outside of a loop...

Comment: I think, using `continue` or  `break` out side loop will just work like an `abort`, since there is not next loop to go to.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it kills all following code if used outside of a loop construct.

The idea of `cfcontinue` is to skip executing all code following the command and to resume processing at the top of the loop.

I guess what is happening is that the cfml engine stops executing code once it gets to the `cfcontinue` command and is looking for where it can resume processing which is unknown if outside of a loop.

Comment: (Edit) @SCP - In addition, if you try the equivalent if statement in CFML, CF throws a context validation error "The tag must be nested inside a cfloop tag". So it sounds like the real issue, or bug if you will, is that cfscript does not warn that the command is being used in a way that was not intended or supported.